# Ajustar zoom via CSS

Tags: css

Quero aplicar zoom no website usando CSS, sei que usando o código `body{font-size: 82.5%};` é possível obter o resultado, porém as imagens continuam com o mesmo tamanho e elementos inseridos via JQuery também continuam com o tamanho anterior. Algum método para aplicar o zoom em todos os elementos?